# Images not working in FB.ui

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Trying to post an image along with wall post was working fine for couple of months with the following code. Suddenly it stopped working.

When I test it with https it doesn't work but in http it works.

The APP URL is using https if the protocol is https and http otherwise.

```
$protocol = "http";
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']!="off")
    $protocol = "https";

define("CANVAS_URL","$protocol://apps.facebook.com/appname/");
define("APP_URL","$protocol://domain.com/content/appname/live/");

FB.ui(
        {

         method: 'feed',
         name: 'my app name',
         link: <? echo "'".CANVAS_URL."'";?>,
         picture: <? echo "'".APP_URL."'";?>+image,
         caption: _caption,
         description: _description
       }, function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) 
         {
           // published
         } else {
           // not published
         }
       }
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not using an SSL URL to get the image (but still using it for your linked CANVAS_URL). Facebook proxies the image requests it shows to users, so even if you're serving it from a non-SSL URL, the image used within Facebook will reach users over SSL.

As to why the SSL URL isn't working, it could be that the crawler used by Facebook to retrieve the image doesn't recognize the certificate chain you're using. Yours worked fine for me in a browser, but when retrieving via `wget` on a Linux command line (likely a closer environment to FB's crawler than a browser is), there's a failure to verify the certificate.

Comment: I tried specifying the image url with :
http://url/to/image/image.png
and also relative like:
image/image.png

None of them worked under https it shows a thin gray bar but doesn't display the image. 

I don't see a request being made to load the image on firebug either.

Comment: Strange - does the exact same feed request work when you're loading the page itself by HTTP, but not HTTPS?

Comment: I'd think there might be a bug here, but this works fine while at https://www.nytimes.com: `FB.ui({'method': 'feed', 'picture': 'http://i1.nyt.com/images/2011/09/18/nyregion/18ADOPT1_SPAN/18ADOPT1_SPAN-hpMedium.jpg', 'link': 'https://shadowytree.com/stsite/' } )`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same 'thin grey bar' as Black Knight on two of the four feed posts on my page.
I took out the https:// and now the all work fine...

was...
picture: 'https://mysite.com/images/' + image,
now...
picture: 'mysite.com/images/' + image,

Answer (score 1):

One thing I just discovered, the image size seems to also play a role.  My picture URL was to the original full size jpg.  And it didn't show.  But after I linked to a much smaller sized version, then it showed!

Comment: What image size did you use?