# Custom image in facebook send dialog?

Tags: facebook, dialog, sendmessage, facebook-ui

I am trying to send a facebook private message via facebook send dialog in my facebook app, i have a problem while setting the custom image each time user clicks on it, i am sending the parameters as

```
<a href="#" onclick="send_message('<?=$transaction->user_id?>', '<?=$transaction->image_name?>')">send msg</a>
```

and on the function side,

```
FB.init({
    appId: '<?=$this->facebook->getAppID()?>', 
    xfbml: true, 
    cookie: true
});
function send_message(user_id, image_name) {
    FB.ui({
        to: user_id,
        method: 'send',
        name: 'The Image',
        description: 'Description here',
        link: 'https://www.something.com/',
        picture: '<?=baseurl()?>imagepath/'+image_name
    });
}
```

It works fine without picture parameter, but all the time it uses default image that facebook automatically pick from my link.

please your kind help will greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTTPS protocol in picture link (if you do so), you might cause your problems. Take a look at [Images not working in FB.ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356668/images-not-working-in-fb-ui)